# Access 2007 Image Capture

Tags: ms-access-2007, image-capture

I have been trying to figure out how to capture an image withing my Microsoft Access 2007 application using a webcam.

We have been paying for a 3rd party application for this in the past - it is used for taking ID card photos, but the software has grown buggy over time, and I think we should be able to accomplish this ourselves!

All I need is for my Access application to use the webcam to capture the image and save it in a network share. That's it!

I have been trying to hunt down vba code, twain drivers, ActiveX controls... but they all seem to be either deprecated (Access 97/2000) or proprietary! There's got to be some other solution out there though!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly shell out to another app (using the vba Shell function) that can take a snapshot from the webcam and save it to a file. I found one example:

http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/snapz-a-command-line-cam-image-grabber/

Good luck.

Comment: AS a very much late response, my solution was to buy the AccessImagine active X control from Bukrek. Has worked like a dream even through the new Office versions and 64 bit and everything. http://access.bukrek.net/